# How can I use Ractive's on-tap attribute with Slim templates?

Tags: slim-lang, ractivejs

In my Slim template, I have:

```
th class=="sortable {{ sortColumn === 'name' ? 'sorted' : '' }}" on-tap=="sort:name" Name
```

This renders:

```
<th class="sortable sorted">Name</th>
```

*The sort method is not being called when the item is clicked.*

Should the `on-tap` attribute work in this case or does it need a different syntax? I have tried Slim's splat attribute:

```
th class=="sortable {{ sortColumn === 'name' ? 'sorted' : '' }}" *({:on-tap => ["sort:name"]})
```

but Slim complains when it hits `on-tap`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: sorry, I misunderstood first time around. Based on this:

> The sort method is not being called when the item is clicked.

I suspect you're mixing up method calls versus events.

If you want to call a method on the ractive instance, the syntax is:

```
on-tap='sort("name")'
```

And would be handled via:

```
new Ractive({
   sort: function(name){

   }
});
```

If you want to raise an event, you would use the syntax you have:

```
on-tap='sort:name'
```

And handle it via:

```
new Ractive({
   oninit: function(){
       this.on('sort', function(event, name){

       });
   }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/yccknhh5/.

Comment: It needs to sort by the name property, not the name value. [According to the tutorial](http://learn.ractivejs.org/list-sections/5), it should not be mustache referenced.

Comment: Also, these `th` tags are not being turned into clickable elements, as in the tutorial. That is why I feel like the `on-tap` property isn't being rendered properly.

Comment: The tutorial never mentioned that `ractive-events-tap.js` is a dependency, so I was working under the assumption that the native library handled this functionality. Your Fiddle allowed me to see that.